How to upload locally persisted data once the user has logged in with Firebase Auth?
There is nice feature when working in offline mode with Firestore:

Cloud Firestore supports offline data persistence. This feature caches
a copy of the Cloud Firestore data that your app is actively using, so
your app can access the data when the device is offline. You can
write, read, listen to, and query the cached data. When the device
comes back online, Cloud Firestore synchronizes any local changes made
by your app to the Cloud Firestore backend.

But what I really need is the same thing: once the user is logged in, in any way (anonymously or using some provider), that all data they created uploads to Firestore.
I ask this because let's say anonymous login is failing or any login is failing, and I need the UID to connect user with his data. I guess this is a realistic scenario, probably very rare, but it can happen.
Is there something in the Firebase API that solves this?

I don't understand how your requirement is different than the statement made by the documentation.  Have you tried it?  Does it work the way you expect?  If not, please edit the question to explain what you tried so we can reproduce and understand what might be wrong.

It differs in the way that in my database I need to store data by user id. If I don't have one if user failed to login, I can only write data without uid. Which makes me thinking, I can listen to auth state change, and enable firestore network when I get uid, and then write it online? Sorry, yes I didn't try. I will get back when I try, but its kinda edge case and I never handled this.. @DougStevenson

If you are trying to store per-user data in Firestore, you definitely need a UID in order to collect that data in a path that makes sense for that user.  You can't reasonably write per-user data without one.
If you are allowing the user to use your app without first signing in, it makes sense to silently and automatically sign them in with anonymous authentication.  This will create an account with a UID that you can use to write documents to Firestore.
When it comes time to sign in the user with whatever real user auth provider you choose, you can upgrade the anonymous account by linking it to the authentication provider.  All of their existing data in Firestore will remain unaffected.

Thanks, but I was just trying to cover the moment when anonymous login fail (or any login).

Then Firestore will be of little help to you, and you need to find another way to persist data locally in your app until the user manages to sign in, then synchronize that yourself.  Allowing Firestore to store data without any sort of authentication is a really bad idea, and cost/security problem waiting to happen.

Can't I just use firestore's disableNetwork method when user is not authenticated?

Maybe.  But then what?  Give it a try and see how it goes.  You'll just run into lots of problems that would be faster and better solved by having a different local store.  Your use case simply isn't covered by Firestore.  Firestore is meant to be offline-also, not offline-first. Anything else is fitting a square peg into a round hole.

I see, thank you... I guess this would be a good example to switch to SwiftData and iCloud.
